# Creating a Moving line in a winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently drawing to draw a line to a form, and then have that line move across the screen, spinning around as well, and being a newbie programmer, I have no idea how to go about doing this. Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit: Added the code that draws the line, very simple I know**

```
public void DrawStick()
    {

        for (int timer = 0; timer < 10; timer++)
        {
            int randnum = rand.Next(-10, 10);
            int startX = startPoint.X + randnum;
            int startY = startPoint.Y + randnum;
            int endX = (int)(startPoint.X + 20 * Math.Cos((double)slope * Math.PI / 180));
            int endY = (int)(startPoint.Y + 20 * Math.Sin((double)slope * Math.PI / 180));
            endPoint = new Point(endX, endY);
            startPoint = new Point(startX, startY);
            slope = (startPoint.Y - endPoint.Y) / (startPoint.X - endPoint.X);
            graObject.DrawLine(myPen, startPoint, endPoint);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            graObject.DrawLine(backgroundPen, startPoint, endPoint);
        }
    }
```

startPoint and endPoint are generated once outside this method.

Comment: Not a full answer but a recommendation, WPF may be easier since there is already hardware acceleration built in and more direct drawing options available.

Comment: let's see your code for the line as you have it now. in theory you will create a function that gets passed a start x/y and end x/y. guts of this function uses some geometric math to plot the lines endpoints through the trip from start to end. one way to call this would be an event handler called something like StartLineMove. try that and show your code if it doesnt work